# 3D scatterplot with regions for different variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot3d

I have a dataset and each entry contains data of a form (`x0,x1,y0,y1`,...).

Suppose that `x0,x1` are cost and `y0,y1` are time.

I want to plot a scatterplot where for each entry a "bubble" is used to display the area captured by (`x0,x1,y0,y1`) in the 2D space, i.e., in the x axis the region `[x0,x1]` and in the y axis the region `[y0,y1]`.

**Update**

For instance, consider this frame

```
x0   x1   y0   y1
1    2    2    3 
1.5  2    2    3.5
```

How can I plot these areas?

Also, what if I want to plot 3D areas of the form

```
x0   x1   y0   y1   z0   z1
1    2    2    3    3    3.5
1.5  2    2    3.5  2.5  3
```

I tried to do this using `geom_point()` but it does not seem to work.  Neither bubble charts can do the job.

@Philip, suggested to use `geom_rect()`, and it might work for the 2D space, but what about 3D?

Any ideas?

**Update 2**

Following Philip's comment, here is my code:

```
library(plot3D)
df <- read.csv(...)
box3D(x0=df$V1, x1 = df$V2, y0=df$V3, y1=df$V4, z0=df$V5, z1=df$V6,
      col = rainbow(n = 8, alpha = 0.1), 
      border = "black", lwd = 2, phi = 0, theta=40,
      ticktype="detailed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question would be easier to answer in general if you provided some sample data, but since you mention `geom_point` I conclude you are using `ggplot2` (good start!), so probably the answer is [`geom_rect`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_rect.html):

```
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = y1, ymax = y2)) +
geom_rect()
```

Or something like that.

Comment: With that example as `df` the indicated example should work. You should get one rectangle per row, and can color/fill them differently by adding additional columns and corresponding calls to `aes(fill=...)` etc. For 3D plotting you cannot use `ggplot2` and should check out packages `rgl` and `plot3D`. Maybe `plot3D::box3D` would be what you're looking for.